# Dropdown Check List Radio Unselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, html-select

I use this very nice plugin in my project called jQuery Dropdown Check List (https://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/) specifically one of example which is named: 'Single select with radio buttons instead of checkboxes'.

One big problem with this example is that I am not able to (I was trying to do this by jQuery) set radio button unchecked. I was using for example:

```
$("input:radio").attr("checked", false);
```

Or

```
$("input:radio").removeAttr("checked");
```

And unfortunately nothing. Can anyone give some advice how fix this thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
- For check:

```
$("input:checkbox").attr("checked", "checked");

or

$("input:checkbox").prop('checked', true);
```

-For uncheck:

```
$("input:checkbox").removeAttr("checked");

or

$("input:checkbox").prop('checked', false);
```

Answer (score 1):

This plugin uses checkbox not radio inputs so you must use $('input:checkbox') or $('input[type="checkbox"]') as your selector!

Click [**here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/RDXsNsrnPWzCNKUY9EEw?p=preview) to see a demo!

Answer (score 1):

I tried both methods in the demo page(http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/dropdownchecklist.html) for the "Single select with radio buttons instead of checkboxes", and turns out to be fine: the selected radio button has removed. However, the value stays in the span because remove selected radio cannot remove selected value.

My suggestion is that after you uncheck the radio, also set a html space to the span, it removes the selected value and also keep the height of its container.